# how to catch Error globally on android?

Tags: android

When an exception occurs, i try to report it to a log server.

i have caught an exception which inherited java.lang.RuntimeException when using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler)`.
but i haven't caught any subclasses that have inherited java.lang.Error. (ex. OutOfMemoryError, IOError, ...)

so i use `Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread hookThread)`, but the `hookThread.run()` method is never called.

how do i catch an Error globally on android?
i do not want to use another process.. i just want to try to report a bug on the log server.

sorry evertyone, i try to catch error throwable continuedly, and i know java.lang.Error also is  caught. but not run implemented function in UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException().

just.. printed log for checking.

Comment: you can just use `adb logcat` with some appropriate filters ...

Comment: i want to send log through network to server.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it. just i was mistake. 
i handled Throwable object to obtained log information.
but i used Throwable.getCause() method, when occurred java.long.Error, it is null.

in uncaughtException() method, when occurred exeption, not print log exactly.

thank you, axis.